# Unable to change the attribute value present in Json using JSONObject

Tags: java, json, selenium-webdriver

I need your help here as my requirement is to have the value for one of the attributes called `transactionReferenceNumber` which comes under JSON path `Request.eventDetails.message` section.

Of course, with little knowledge on the JSON path traversing I was able to traverse till `Request.eventDetails.message` using `JSONObject` as shown in below snippet code, but unable to traverse in `message` section and get or change the value for `transactionReferenceNumber` attribute or any other attribute.

```java
String filepath = System.getProperty("user.dir") +
    "/src/test/resources/Json_Files/Payment_Events_Api_PayLoad.json";
String jsonContents = new String((Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(filepath))));
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonContents);
            
String Message = jsonObject.getJSONObject("request")
    .getJSONObject("eventDetails")
    .get("message")
    .toString();
```

Below is the JSON for your reference:

```json
{
    "metadata": {
        "requestId": "e1d0db1f-ac7d-4011-b34e-c063b6d638a6",
        "signature": "ZwcQa6YozllV1mLWPrZFiacSguRoEibSgmb97UvTrWgvuY5I76eWuAg==",
        "signatureAlgorithm": "SH443222wesd"
    },
    "request": {
        "eventId": "e43e2222-2c91-47d8-8c03-9a5f52db15a2",
        "eventCode": "EADFE",
        "eventCategory": "PAYMENT_STATUS",
        "eventType": "TRANSACTION_STATUS",
        "eventDetails": {
            "paymentProduct": "CXC",
            "message": "{ \"achCompanyId\": \"3131231\", \"companyName\": \"ABC Company\", \"transactionReferenceNumber\": \"4333\", \"remittanceInfo\": \"Paroll Processing\", \"processingDate\": \"2022-01-12\", \"payeeFirstname\": \"John\", \"payeeIDType\": \"email\", \"payeeEmail\": \"abc.Doe@gmail.com\", \"payeeMobile\": \"\", \"paymentType\": \"STANDARD\", \"paymentAmount($)\": 600.50, \"numberOfHoldDays\": 5, \"currentPaymentStatus\": \"PENDING\"}",
            "messageFormat": "CUSTOM.CXC.JSON"
        },
        "timeStamp": "2020-07-21T14:53:54-0400"
    }
}
```

Please, request in all to help me on this issue and also suggest the possible way to tackle this problem.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "message" value in your JSON is a string containing another JSON object, not a direct JSON object, meaning that you cannot traverse it directly using `getJSONObject()` or similar methods. What you need to do is to parse the "message" as a separate JSON object, and only then you can modify its values:

```java
String filepath = System.getProperty("user.dir") +
    "/src/test/resources/Json_Files/Payment_Events_Api_PayLoad.json";
String jsonContents = new String((Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(filepath))));
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonContents);
            
String messageStr = jsonObject.getJSONObject("request")
    .getJSONObject("eventDetails")
    .getString("message");

// get message separately
JSONObject messageJson = new JSONObject(messageStr);

// modify your value
messageJson.put("transactionReferenceNumber", "NewValue");

// replace the old message string with the modified one
jsonObject.getJSONObject("request")
    .getJSONObject("eventDetails")
    .put("message", messageJson.toString());
```

Comment: Cool. Thanks a lot and really appreciate your timely help. I understood and your logic is works fine.